# Defaults not set in Rails multiple-select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

In my application, one article can have multiple tags.  When creating an article, I am able to add multiple tags to an article using a multiple-select dropdown and the Rails Select2 gem.

The problem is that when I edit the article, none of the tags are selected, and a user has to select them all over again.

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :tags, options_for_select(@tags.collect {|t| [ t.id, t.title] }),{:selected=>@article.tags}, :multiple => true, :id => "article_tags", :class => "form-control" %><br>
  <%= f.submit 'Update', :class => "btn" %><br>
<% end %>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#article_tags").select2({multiple:true});
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do `@tags` and `@article.tags` contain?

Comment: Does it work without select2 gem? because I remember having some problem setting the selected for it.

Comment: replace `tags` with `tag_ids`.

Comment: @adamliesko `@tags` was for text like this: `tag one, tag two, tag 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working when I put it at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tags").select2({multiple:true});
    $('select').select2().select2('val', 'tag one, tag two, tag three');
    $('select').select2();
  });
</script>
```